# have a DLL report back to a main form

Tags: .net, visual-studio, design-patterns

I am building a .NET solution with a GUI mode(one project) and a console mode (another project). Each of these projects references a shared class library that holds the shared logical guts behind each app. I want the DLL to be as isolated as possible from each client application. how can I have the DLL report progress to the gui? Right now, the GUI project references the DLL. VS2010 / .NET won't let me reference the GUI from the DLL because it would be a circular reference.

How can I do this? Are there any general principles for how to handle this in .NET design, or software design in general? Is there a way to use a callback without a reference to the calling project?

Comment: Sounds like you need a custom event in your DLL which can be defined in your GUI project.

Comment: but how can I raise an custom event from the GUI in the ddl without a reference?

Comment: The dll code defines an event and executes the event at some point. It doesn't know what is registered to the event. The gui defines the function to assign to the event handler.

Comment: Do if the DLL has no ref to the GUI, but throws a XYZ error ... and the GUI handles an XYZ error... then the GUI will handle the XYZ error even though the DLL does not know about the GUI?

Comment: Isn't that how it always works? If you use code in a DLL that throws and unhandled error and you catch that error in your GUI, then that makes sense. The DLL never needed to know about the GUI. Why would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need a custom event in your DLL that you then attach to in your GUI.

Here's some code to make it more understandable.

First off lets create a mock of our DLL that does something similar to loading and also defines an event we can attach to in our GUI that received the completed percentage:

```
public class MyDLLType
{
  public decimal PercentageComplete = 5;

  public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> StatusChanged;

  public virtual void OnStatusChanged(CustomEventArgs e)
  {
   if(StatusChanged != null)
   {
      StatusChanged(this, e);
   }
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {

     var eventArgs = new CustomEventArgs();
     eventArgs.PercentageComplete = PercentageComplete;

     OnStatusChanged(eventArgs);

     if(PercentageComplete < 100)
     {
       Thread.Sleep(500);
       PercentageComplete++;
       DoSomething();
     }
  }
}
```

Now we have a mock DLL that exposes a `StatusChanged` event for our GUI to hook into. Here's a mock GUI taking advantage of this:

```
public class MyGUI
{
void Main()
{
    var myNiceDLLType = new MyDLLType();
    myNiceDLLType.StatusChanged += UpdateStatusChange;
    myNiceDLLType.DoSomething();
}

public void UpdateStatusChange(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
{
 var percentageComplete = e.PercentageComplete;
 Console.WriteLine(percentageComplete);
}
}
```

and Bingo, our GUI is receiving the complete percentage from the DLL without the DLL needing to know anything about the GUI.

The CustomEventArgs I used above looks like this:

```
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public decimal PercentageComplete{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to break the circular reference is to create another library that both modules reference.

Another option is to use events that can be raised by the logic DLL and handled in the gui/console part

Answer (score 0):

If design is such, that it need circular reference, IMHO, you should redesign that portion of code where it is necessary.

I would suggest to put relevent code to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)